# Expected NUMBER got DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting an SQL error that makes no sense to me. I created a table called SUBORDER using this command:

```
CREATE TABLE SUBORDER (
  OrderNo int, 
  SuborderNo int, 
  ReqShipDate date, 
  ActualShipDate date, 
  BranchName varchar(50), 
  primary key (OrderNo, SuborderNo), 
  foreign key (OrderNo) references ORDERS(OrderNo) on delete set null, 
  foreign key (BranchName) references BRANCH(BranchName) on delete set null
);
```

As you can see, ReqShipDate and ActualShipDate were declared as dates. But then when I run this code:

```
create or replace trigger shipment_late
before update
    on SUBORDER
for each row
declare
    reqdate DATE;
    actualdate DATE;

begin
select s.ReqShipDate, s.ActualShipDate into reqdate, actualdate 
    from SUBORDER s 
    where ( s.OrderNo = :new.OrderNo ) and ( s.SuborderNo = :new.SuborderNo );

if reqdate > actualdate then
    insert into LATE_SHIPMENT 
        select * from SUBORDER s 
        where ( s.OrderNo = :new.OrderNo ) and ( s.SuborderNo = :new.SuborderNo );
end if;

end;
```

the SQL console tells me:

> Error(12,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected
>   NUMBER got DATE

Why is it expecting a number?

Comment: Can you post the results of `DESC LATE_SHIPMENT`?

Comment: Without an explicit column list in the `insert`, anything could be happening.

Comment: If you solve this error (presumably by doing an explicit column list for the `insert` and the `select`), you're going to hit a mutating table error. A row-level trigger on `suborder` cannot query `suborder` in general. Your first `select` seems pointless, presumably you just want `:new.ReqShipDate` and `:new.ActualShipDate` so you don't need to query the table.  Your subsequent `insert` should be an `insert values` where you list out the various `:new.columnName` attributes that you want to insert in the `values` clause (in addition to specifying a column list for the `insert`)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you just want

```
create or replace trigger shipment_late
before update
    on SUBORDER
for each row
begin
  if :new.ReqShipDate > :new.ActualShipDate
  then
    insert into LATE_SHIPMENT( <<list of columns>> )
      values( :new.OrderNo, :new.SuborderNo, ... ); 
  end if;
end;
```

A couple things to be aware of

- It's always a good idea to explicitly list out the columns if you're doing an `insert` statement.  Otherwise, you're relying on an implicit order that isn't going to be obvious to someone reading your code and that creates quite a bit of potential for errors.  Listing out the columns, at a minimum, documents what values you are putting where.  In this example, it seems unlikely that the `late_shipment` table has exactly the same set of columns in `suborder` defined in exactly the same order.
- In general, a row-level trigger on a table (`SubOrder` in this case) cannot query that table.  Doing so will generally raise a mutating table exception.  That doesn't appear to be necessary here, however.  You just need to reference the various attributes of the `:new` pseudo-record.